# Web2py is not connecting with my MySQL database

Tags: python, connection, web2py, dreamhost

I have a system running on Google App Engine in Python with web2py.
Before it was connected with a Google Cloud SQL database.
Now I need it to connect to a database at DreamHost.

```
db = DAL ('mysql: // User: senha@mysql-apollo-apollo.apollosolucoes.com/bancodedados' driver_args = {
        }, Migrate_enabled = False, lazy_tables = True)
```

This generating me this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/base/data/home/apps/s~apollo-solutionworkshop/teste2.386857474473035619/gluon/restricted.py",
>   line 220, in restricted
>       exec ccode in environment   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~apollo-solutionworkshop/teste2.386857474473035619/applications/frontend/models/b_db.py",
>   line 12, in 
>       }, Migrate_enabled = False, lazy_tables = True)   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~apollo-solutionworkshop/teste2.386857474473035619/gluon/dal.py",
>   line 7867, in **init**
>       raise RuntimeError ("Failure to connect, tried% d times: \ n% s"% (attempts, tb)) RuntimeError: Failure to connect, tried 5 times:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/base/data/home/apps/s~apollo-solutionworkshop/teste2.386857474473035619/gluon/dal.py",
>   line 7845, in **init**
>       self._adapter = ADAPTERS [self._dbname] (** kwargs)   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~apollo-solutionworkshop/teste2.386857474473035619/gluon/dal.py",
>   line 688, in **call**
>       obj = super (AdapterMeta, cls) .__ call __ (* args, ** kwargs)   File
>   "/base/data/home/apps/s~apollo-solutionworkshop/teste2.386857474473035619/gluon/dal.py"
>   line in 2728, in **init**
>       if do_connect: self.reconnect ()   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~apollo-solutionworkshop/teste2.386857474473035619/gluon/dal.py",
>   line 648, in reconnect
>       self.connection = f ()   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~apollo-solutionworkshop/teste2.386857474473035619/gluon/dal.py"
>   line in 2726, in connector
>       self.driver.connect return (** driver_args)   File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/MySQLdb-1.2.4b4/MySQLdb/**init**.py",
>   line 81, in Connect
>       return Connection (* args, ** kwargs)   File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/MySQLdb-1.2.4b4/MySQLdb/connections.py",
>   line 190, in **init**
>       super (Connection, self) .__ init __ (* args, ** kwargs2) OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host
>   'mysql-apollo-apollo.apollosolucoes.com' (-1)")

Putting that host more User and password, and database in the program SQLyog I can connect perfectly.

When the connection was made to go to the Google Cloud SQL database went like this:

```
'unix_socket' '/ cloudsql / apollo-solutionworkshop: apollosystem-main'
```

Comment: I hope you didn't post the actual login credentials here, in this public forum.

Comment: both as User password and the database name are fake

Comment: Why there is no port specify in your connection string?

Comment: Even when I put the door did not work out.
It was thus with the port.

'db = DAL ('mysql: // User: senha@mysql-apollo-apollo.apollosolucoes.com: 3306 / bancodedados' driver_args = {
         }, Migrate_enabled = False, lazy_tables = True)'


I'm closing this post, because I contacted the support of Dreamhost and they did an internal procedure to fix this problem.
As I will not need more because the company changed what was to be done.
I appreciate the help of all.

Comment: You may consider deleting your question then...